# Calendly hide cookies banner using iframe

Tags: css, cookies, iframe, calendly

I have embedded calendly in website using iframe. The code works fine as mentioned below. However, when i try to hide cookie banner and hide page details using the code mentioned by calendly,its not working. I am trying to reutilise the calendly code in an iframe.I would appreciate any help.Ideal solution is to hide the banner. If that is not possible, then next best solution would be to reduce the banner size to the size of calendar.

website : dishasharma.ca
url : https://www.dishasharma.ca/products/happiness-and-purpose-coaching-per-session
screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn5kc.png

```
<iframe id="myIframe" width="100%" height="1050px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"> 
</iframe>

<script>
    let myIframe = document.getElementById("myIframe");
    let url_string = "https://calendly.com/disha_sharma/session";
    let calendlyBackgroundColor = "background_color=e9f4f5"; 
    let calendlyHidePageDetails = "hide_landing_page_details=1"; // code not working 
    let calendlyHideBanner = "hide_gdpr_banner=1"; // code not working 
    let adsURL = url_string+"?"+calendlyHideBanner+"&"+calendlyHidePageDetails+"&"+calendlyBackgroundColor; // code not working 

    myIframe.src = adsURL;
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1050px) {
    iframe#myIframe{
     height="850px";
}
</style>
```

Original calendly code to embed in website and hide the banner :

```
<!-- Calendly inline widget begin -->
<div class="calendly-inline-widget" data-url="https://calendly.com/disha_sharma/session?hide_landing_page_details=1&hide_gdpr_banner=1&background_color=e9f4f5" style="min-width:320px;height:1050px;"</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js" async></script>
<!-- Calendly inline widget end -->

<style type="text/css">
@media only screen and (min-width: 1050px) {
    .calendly-inline-widget{
     height:850px; 
}
</style>
```

Comment: Did you able to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

This issue can be solved by adding two extra parameters to the existing link:
`&embed_domain=YOUR.DOMAIN.ANY` and `&embed_type=Inline`

So in the end, it should be looks like this:

`https://calendly.com/YOUR_EVENT?hide_gdpr_banner=1&embed_domain=YOUR.DOMAIN.ANY&embed_type=Inline`

Please don't ask why it's not in the Calendly documentation, but this is the solution from their support.

I hope it helps! =)